# Select results from one query to another

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE 'test%';
```

That would show me all the ids in table1 with the id of anything that matched test%. So I have been doing this the long way doing this :

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = '1011';
```

Is there anyway to make my table1 query jump and auto insert to WHERE id = '1011', I'd like it to auto match it up whats in query one to query two. Instead of having to run the second query over and over again and get all the results faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table2 a
JOIN table1 b
  ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.name LIKE 'test%'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, is there anyway to remove the formatting from table1 as it has about 30 colums?

Comment: Yes, use `b.value`  (for `table1`) for every value from `table1` that you want to select.

Comment: If you just want columns from table1, then change `*` to `a.*`. Or list out the columns you want, `a.col1, a.col2, b.col3`, etc.